# given 2 center coordinates, how to find all Rectangle axes?

Tags: javascript, math, geometry

for a game I'm building, I need to draw a rectangle on two sides of a line made from two coordinates.

I have an image illustrating this "hard to ask" question.

given coordinates (-4,3) and (3, -4) 
given that the width of the rectangle will be 4 (for example)
I need to find all (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (x3, y3), (x4, y4)

** I need to write this in Javascript eventually.

your help is much appreciated. [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've tried to solve this using javascript & canvas. The problem is that the coordinates in canvas are upside down, I suppose you already know this. Also since your rect would be extremely small, I've multiplied your numbers by 10.

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
let cw = canvas.width = 300,
  cx = cw / 2;
let ch = canvas.height = 300,
  cy = ch / 2;


const rad = Math.PI / 180;
ctx.translate(cx,cy)

//axis
ctx.strokeStyle = "#d9d9d9";
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(-cx,0);
ctx.lineTo(cx,0);
ctx.moveTo(0,-cy);
ctx.lineTo(0,cy);
ctx.stroke();


// your data
let p1={x:-40,y:30};
let p2={x:30,y:-40};
// the angle of the initial line
let angle = Math.atan2(p2.y-p1.y, p2.x-p1.x);
// the center of the line
let c = 
  {  x: p1.x + (p2.x - p1.x)/2,
     y: p1.y + (p2.y - p1.y)/2
  }


let w = dist(p1, p2);//the width of the rect
let h = 60;//the height of the rect

// draw the initial line
line(p1,p2);
// draw the center as a red point
marker(c);

// calculate the opoints of the rect
function rectPoints(w,h){
  let p1 = {
  x : c.x -w/2,
  y : c.y -h/2
  }
  let p2 = {
  x : c.x + w/2,
  y : c.y -h/2
  }
  let p3 = {
  x : c.x + w/2,
  y : c.y +h/2
  }
  let p4 = {
  x : c.x -w/2,
  y : c.y +h/2
  }
  
  // this rotate all the points relative to the center c
  return [
    rotate(p1,c, angle),
    rotate(p2,c, angle),
    rotate(p3,c, angle),
    rotate(p4,c, angle)
  ]
}


// draw the rect

ctx.strokeStyle = "blue";
drawRect(rectPoints(w,h));

// some helpful functions
function line(p1,p2){
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(p1.x,p1.y);
  ctx.lineTo(p2.x,p2.y);
  ctx.stroke();
}

function dist(p1, p2) {
  let dx = p2.x - p1.x;
  let dy = p2.y - p1.y;
  return Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
}

function marker(p,color){
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.fillStyle = color || "red";
  ctx.arc(p.x,p.y,4,0,2*Math.PI);
  ctx.fill();
}

function rotate(p,c, angle){
  let cos = Math.cos(angle);
  let sin = Math.sin(angle);
  return {
  x: c.x + (p.x - c.x) * cos - (p.y - c.y) * sin,
  y: c.y + (p.x - c.x) * sin + (p.y - c.y) * cos
  }
}

function drawRect(points){
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(points[0].x,points[0].y);
  ctx.lineTo(points[1].x,points[1].y);
  ctx.lineTo(points[2].x,points[2].y);
  ctx.lineTo(points[3].x,points[3].y);
  ctx.lineTo(points[0].x,points[0].y);
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.stroke();
}
```

```css
canvas{border:1px solid #d9d9d9}
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

Comment: thank you very much!! you are a great help. but there is some weird thing is happening when i am setting p1={x:0,y:0} and p2={x:0,y:50}. its like the box is below the the zero line, like it needs to be mirrored. and also, I see the value of Y to be '-3.061..' shouldn't it be zero?

Comment: Thank you Roey Zada for your feedback. Since you are saying "its like the box is below the the zero line" I assume that you are not acquainted with the canvas coordinate system in HTML5. I may be wrong. This [youtube explains how  the canvas coordinate system works](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RMUxP3ZNTEI).

Answer (score 2):

Points A, B form vector

```
M.X = B.X - A.X
M.Y = B.Y - A.Y
```

Perpendicular vector

```
P.X = -M.Y
P.Y =  M.X
```

Length of P:

```
Len = Math.sqrt(P.X*P.X + P.Y*P.Y)
```

Normalized (unit) perpendicular:

```
 uP.X = P.X / Len
 uP.Y = P.Y / Len
```

Points

```
 X1 = A.X + uP.X * HalfWidth
 Y1 = A.Y + uP.Y * HalfWidth
(X4, Y4) = (A.X - uP.X * HalfWidth, A.Y - uP.Y * HalfWidth)
and similar for points 2 and 3 around B
```

Comment: thank you! but can you please do this in Javascript?

Comment: No, I cannot, but I separated complex expressions into simpler ones